# Sort data when using ImportJSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am using a Google Sheets to extact survey data from an app, based on using [ImportJSON script](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json).

Is there a way to get the data sorted A-Z before the data is loaded into GS?

Once the data is in GS if I try to sort the data the link just puts the data back into its original shape.

`=ImportJSON("https://xxxxx.net/json?key=Mg.Clxt6A.TV1DFtPA0k8Ehpb0RDxyLH7xhU8", "/elements", ",noTruncate,Headers")`

Comment: You can't sort data before you load it, the original data is in JSON format anyways. JSON contains a un-ordered collection of name/value pairs. You will need to sort the two-dimensional array that the function returns.

Comment: Thanks, Spencer, I will do some searching to see what I can find

Comment: GS is probably Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: So you want to sort the table first, then add a row at the bottom. Is that sequence essential? Can it be inserted, then sorted? Can the API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#sort_rows not be used?

Comment: This worked `=Sort(ImportJSON("https://xxxxx.net/json?key=Mg.Clxt6A.TV1DFtPA0k8Ehpb0RDxyLH7xhU8", "/elements", ",noTruncate,Headers"),13,true)` where I am `sorting` on column `13`